# Hibernate's StaleObjectStateException still thrown after entity reloaded

Tags: java, hibernate, session, optimistic-locking

I am playing with a standard optimistic concurrency control scenario with extended session / automatic versioning. I have an entity which I load in the first transaction, present to user for modification and save in the second one, both transactions sharing the same session. After the entity is somehow modified `session.flush()` at the end of the second transaction may throw a `StaleObjectStateException` in case a version inconsistency is detected meaning that a concurrent transaction has saved a next version of the entity in between.

I want to handle such an error in a most simple way -- just to reload entity losing current changes and continue with editing and saving again. First I tried this:

```
session.refresh(entity);
```

but after I modify and attempt to save this refreshed entity, I still get the same `StaleObjectStateException`, even though it does get refreshed and the version number appears consistent; yes I know that using `refresh()` in extended sessions is [discouraged](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#refresh%28java.lang.Object%29), but don't understand why. Is this behavior related to the reason it is discouraged?

Next I tried the following way to avoid using `session.refresh()`:

```
session.evict(entity);
entity = session.load(MyEntity.class, id);
```

but it still results in `StaleObjectStateException` being raised at saving the entity which is not indeed stale.

The only way I managed to cope with the exception is this:

```
session.clear();
entity = session.load(MyEntity.class, id);
```

but isn't `session.clear()` the same as `session.evict()` pertaining to my concrete entity?

To resume, my questions are:

- Why is `StaleObjectStateException` still thrown on a reloaded entity unless `session.clear()` is done?
- What is the correct way to reload an entity which has already been loaded in the same session and why is `refresh()` bad? Is there something wrong with this approach to implement conversation?

I'm using Hibernate 4.1.7.Final, with no second-level cache.

My apologies if my question is repeating, but I fail to find a profound explanation...

Comment: Are you sure the `StaleObjectStateException` pertains to `MyEntity` with your `id`? Maybe it's about a different entity. That would be the answer to why `clear()` works and `evict()` does not.

Comment: @ShyJ Yes, debugging is showing me that the session is keeping only one instance before the exception is thrown. The problem was evidently in the session being unusable after an exception was thrown from one of its methods, as @Johanna pointed out. So `clear()` working here is just a side-effect we should ignore. Thank you anyway for your interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get an exception in a session, than that session instance is broken. You cannot use that instance any more and you have to throw it away and create a new instance. The exception is not reset (as you can see you get the same exception again thought logically this should not happen). This is a general rule for using hibernate sessions. The reason for this is, hibernate does not always see why an exception appears and the state of the session instance may be inconsistent.

I don't know why it works after clear(). This may be accidentally. It is more prudent to use a new instance.

If you use a StatelessSession, then you don't have this restriction, but stateless sessions have other disadvantages, for example no caching.

Comment: Thank you Johanna, I really missed this [very important thing](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html) that "If the Session throws an exception, the transaction must be rolled back and the **session discarded**". So I don't have to refresh but just re-read data in a new session instead in my case. But is it safe using [`refresh()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#refresh(java.lang.Object)) in order to re-read data in the same session when no exception occurs? It's not obvious from the javadoc.

Comment: refresh() in the same session should be safe as long as no exception occurs.